# Wordpress Theme Options field not retaining value

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm having what im sure is a simple issue but i can't manage to figure it out.

I'm coding a theme options page for my wordpress template and i've managed to get it where the values are saved and i can use them on the site but whenever i reload the theme options page all the form fields are blank and any previously applied settings are gone. My code is below.

```
<?php
    //Theme Options Functionality is Below
if (get_option('pardue_theme_options')){
        $theme_options = get_option('pardue_theme_options');
} else {
    add_option('pardue_theme_options', array(
            'sidebar2_on' => true,
            'footer_text' => 'Made by William'

        ));


}
?>




 <?php add_action('admin_menu', 'theme_page_add');
function theme_page_add() {
    add_submenu_page('themes.php', 'Pardue Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'administrator',  'themeoptions', 'theme_page_options');

}
function theme_page_options() {

        global $theme_options;



        $new_values = array(
            'footer_text' => htmlentities($_POST['footer_text'], ENT_QUOTES),


            );

        update_option('pardue_theme_options', $new_values);

        $theme_options = get_option('pardue_theme_options');

    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<h2>Theme Options</h2>';
?>
<form action="themes.php?page=themeoptions" method="post">


<label for="footer_text">Footer Text: </label><input name="footer_text" id="footer_text" value="<?php echo $theme_options['footer_text']; ?>" /> <br /> <br /> 

<label for="sidebar_checkbox">Sidebar 2 on: </label> <input name="sidebar_checkbox" id="sidebar_checkbox" value="on" type="checkbox" /> <br /> <br />

<input type="submit" value="Update Options" name="submit" />

</form>

<?php
    echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: the 'sidebar2_on' => true, can be ignored. it's for a field i no longer need.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for coding my theme options. The plugin at the link below makes it very easy to code up theme options.

[Link to plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-theme-options/)

Documentation is included when you activate the plugin.